# Merge Pandas Multiindexed DataFrame with Singleindexed Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I would like to join two DataFrames. The first one is a multi indexed DataFrame and the second is a simple DataFrame.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': {('x', 0) : 1, ('x', 1) : 2, ('y', 0): 3, ('y', 1): 5}, 'b': {('x', 0) : 2, ('x', 1) : 4, ('y', 0): 2, ('y', 1): 7}}).T
print(a)

#    x     y
#    0  1  0  1
# a  1  2  3  5
# b  2  4  2  7

b = pd.DataFrame({'y': np.arange(10), 'z': np.arange(10, 20)})

magical_merge(left=a, right=b, on='y')

#    x     y     z
#    0  1  0  1  0  1 
# a  1  2  3  5 13 15
# b  2  4  2  7 12 17
```

Right now I am doing this with a loop over the second index like this:

```py
merged = []
for l in [0, 1]:
   m = pd.merge(left=a.xs(l, axis=1, level=1),right=b, on='y')
   m_indices = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([m.columns, [l]])
   m.columns = m_indices
   merged.append(m)

result = pd.concat(merged, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Can pandas do this somehow by itself?

Comment: So you want to merge the Z values that correspond to the Y values in the original dataframe?

Comment: yes, but I want to keep the structure of the Y values in the resulting dataframe (the multiindexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `stack` and `reset_index` on the multiindex `df` (which is `a` in your case). Next, `merge` and `set_index` back. Finally, use `rename_axis` to pretty the multiindex names and `unstack` to put back multiindex columns:

```
a.stack().reset_index().merge(b, on='y').set_index(['level_0', 'level_1']) \
                       .rename_axis(index=[None, None]).unstack()

Out[335]:
   x     y      z
   0  1  0  1   0   1
a  1  2  3  5  13  15
b  2  4  2  7  12  17
```